# FFmpeg: How to merge all audio streams into stereo

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have 4 audio streams in my video file. They are from 4 microphones placed at 4 different people speaking. I want to transcode to a preview file that can be listened to on headphones where everybody's voice can be heard.

I have seen the -ac 2 option, but I can't tell if this will merge all the audio streams or just select the 1st two. I've also seen the amerge filter, but the docs say this will produce 4 audio channels in the output file. So I'm wondering how headphones will deal with the additional 2 channels

Comment: by definition headphones can only render at most 2 channels (stereo) so any extra channel must get added into one of those channels before getting sent to headphones ... give it a go using ffmpeg and show us what you have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options. This assumes each individual audio stream in `in.mp4` is mono.

## Mono

Using the [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter and `-ac 1`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" -ac 1 -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy out.mp4
```

With [amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]amix=inputs=4[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy out.mp4
```

## Stereo

With amerge and `-ac 2`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" -ac 2 -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy out.mp4
```

## Manually mixed stereo

Using amerge and [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) with custom downmix:

- Channel 0 will be 100% in FL
- Channel 1 will be 75% in FL & 25% in FR
- Channel 2 will be 25% in FL & 75% in FR
- Channel 3 will be 100% in FR

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]amerge=inputs=4,pan=stereo|FL<c0+0.75*c1+0.25*c2|FR<0.25*c1+0.75*c2+c3[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy out.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [amerge audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge-1), used to solve this similar question: [How do I use ffmpeg to merge all audio streams (in a video file) into one audio channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824127/how-do-i-use-ffmpeg-to-merge-all-audio-streams-in-a-video-file-into-one-audio?rq=1)

[amix](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix) should even better should fit your purpose.