# How to implement ffmpeg filter_complex in c++ code?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to implement C++ code which uses an FFmpeg filter to merge 2 mono audio streams from input video into 1 stereo stream. The filter itself can be found easily enough in several sources:

[FFmpeg: How to merge all audio streams into stereo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060729/ffmpeg-how-to-merge-all-audio-streams-into-stereo)

http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/amerge.htm.gz

My question relates to how I can implement this in code. I am using the exact same code found in the FFmpeg examples here:
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering_audio_8c-example.html

I just change the filter_descr variable to:

```
static const char *filter_descr = "[0:1][0:2] amerge=inputs=2";
```

When I use this I get the following exception:
Output pad "default" with type audio of the filter instance "in" of a buffer not connected to any destination
I get an Invalid Argument -22 exception when I'm configuring the filter graph

```
if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, NULL)) < 0)
```

Comment: The C++ code I used above actually relates to video filters while the filter I was trying to apply is a complex filter. I couldn't find any documentation on how to apply complex filters using the FFmpeg API.

Comment: Did you find out the solution? I run into the same thing.