# CMD equivalent of linux wc -l command within a call to FFPROBE?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

This answer would solve a lot of my problems but relies on wc -l to tally the number of audio channels from the output of ffprobe.

[How do I use ffmpeg to merge all audio streams (in a video file) into one audio channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45824127/how-do-i-use-ffmpeg-to-merge-all-audio-streams-in-a-video-file-into-one-audio?rq=1)

I'm using a Windows batch file, so I need another way of accomplishing the following in CMD:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=1,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2[video];[0:a]amerge=inputs=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream=codec_type -of csv=p=0 input.mov | wc -l),atempo=24000/24024[audio]"
```

Any help?  My programming experience is minimal.  This question seems like it's asking the same thing, but I can't seem to adapt its suggestions into the ffprobe call with the end result being it just returning a number.

[What is the windows equivalent of Linux command wc -l?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976223/what-is-the-windows-equivalent-of-linux-command-wc-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested as I don't have your programs installed.  But essentially what you need to do is capture the output of ffprobe with a `FOR /F` command.  You will pipe the output of FFPROBE to the `FIND` command to get a non empty line count.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a -show_entries stream^=codec_type -of csv^=p^=0 input.mov ^| find /v /c ""') do set "count=%%G"
```

You can then use the variable `%count%` with your FFMPEG command.

Comment: this worked a charm--thank you so much!  Now I can adapt this and use ffprobe to generate all kinds of data, and then decide upon further processing based upon file properties.  Amazing.  You've made my day!

Comment: The `^` is an escape character.  It is needed when special characters are inside the `IN` clause of a `FOR /F` command.

Comment: thanks!  I spotted they were always preceding "=", so suspected that might be the case.